# Azure WebJobs Vs DataFactory

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-data-factory

For analytic/reports specific project, I need to ingest data from Web API response into Azure SQL Table / Azure Data Lake.
I am confused with using the WebJobs Vs DataFactory for the data Ingestion.

Should I use Azure SQL Table or Azure Data Lake ?

Comment: For Data Ingestion the On premise Web api is suppose to return data is synchronized 1 time per hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL Database is a SQL Server. Azure Data Lake can be viewed as an "infinite" HDD.
The choice will depend on the way you want to store and use the data, the volume too.
If you need to store large amount of structured data, you should also consider Azure SQL Datawarehouse.

To ingest data, you have several solutions. You can have a look at this link : 
 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-copy-wizard
 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs

Azure Data Factory is designed to load large amount of data (millions of records).